# Mysql query - how to force sign "_" in pattern matching?

Tags: mysql

I have in database TEST these values for example:

```
ID
1_0    
1_1
10_1
11_1
```

If I want select all values ​​at the beginning with number "1", but not "10" or "11" then I have created my request in that way:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id LIKE '1_%';
```

But sign `_` for Mysql Query also means one character from name so result of this will be all the values from the list.

My question is - how to force query to think that `_` is a character in ID name, not sign of any letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to just escape the _ like so:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id LIKE '1\_%';
```